# Updating a column twice in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to know what this query will do:

```
UPDATE users SET
PaymentAmount = PaymentAmount + TempPaymentAmount,
PaymentDuration = PaymentDuration + TempPaymentDuration,
TempPaymentAmount = NULL,
TempPaymentDuration = NULL
WHERE UserID = 1234
```

You'll notice that I am trying to copy a value from temp column to the original column and nullify it at the same time. I am wondering if the query will do what I expect.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't just run it and find out?

Comment: @Connell: live database... bad idea.

Comment: But the scenario is so simple - it should be no problem to create a new table on a testserver and try it out...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For instance values in row (UserId=1234) are following:

```
PaymentAmount = 10
PaymentDuration = 30 
TempPaymentDuration = 40
TempPaymentAmount = 50
```

After the query execution:

```
PaymentAmount = PaymentAmount + TempPaymentAmount = 60
PaymentDuration = PaymentDuration + TempPaymentDuration = 70
TempPaymentAmount = NULL
TempPaymentDuration = NULL
```

---

[MySQL 12.2.10. UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html)

> If you access a column from the table to be updated in an expression,
>   UPDATE uses the current value of the column. For example, the
>   following statement sets col1 to one more than its current value:
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1;
> ```

Also an interestign point:

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

Comment: Any chance MySQL decides to do things the other way round, like NULLify first, add later?

Comment: @Salman A: even if behaviour will be changed - your would not be affected until upgrade to the newer version. And before each verison upgrate you always should read documentation and be aware of new version changes before upgrading so you can update your queries as well

Comment: @sll: I won't be around by then :p

Comment: @Salman A: In theory, it is generally not a good idea to use queries which rely on kinks and implementation details of the target system... in theory. On the other hand MySQL kinks are what's causing the dilemma in the first place so chances are future updates will try and move towards an SQL compliant implementation rather than something else.

Comment: I ran the queries on a test table which appeared to work as described.

Answer (score 1):

Should work, according to the docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

> Single-table UPDATE assignments are generally evaluated from left to
>   right. For multiple-table updates, there is no guarantee that
>   assignments are carried out in any particular order.

So, if you run it, it should perform all `SET` queries one by one, thus using the original value first, then nullifying it.

Comment: It is the word *generally* that is confusing me.

Comment: Haha, you're right, it doesn't sound very confident. However, this comes straight from the people who've cobbled it together, so the only way to get more assurance is to actually try it, I guess...

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you give it a try and execute it?

The answer is yes: When you use values from columns that you modify in the same query, the database engine will take the unmodified values while calculating the updated values.

Comment: The above-mentioned answer states otherwise: the database will use the *updated* column value, not the original.

Comment: Ähm, which answer(s) are you referring to? All answers tell you, that the original (or current) value will be used - not teh updated ...

Answer (score 0):

It should do.. My understanding of what is actually happening is:#

```
UPDATE users SET
:New.PaymentAmount = :Old.PaymentAmount + :Old.TempPaymentAmount,
:New.PaymentDuration = :Old.PaymentDuration + :Old.TempPaymentDuration,
:New.TempPaymentAmount = NULL,
:New.TempPaymentDuration = NULL
WHERE UserID = 1234
```